# Showing there is a triangle in a graph with degree constraints on vertices

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

A warm up problem from the Canadian Winter Camp problems reads as follows:

> There are three colleges in a town. Each college has n students. Any student of any college knows n+1 students of the other two colleges. Prove that it is possible to choose a student from each of the three colleges so that all three students would know each other.

My attempt: For $n=2$, it is easy to construct explicit examples. In terms of adjacency matrix $A$ of the graph, the number of triangles in a graph is $\dfrac{tr(A)}{6}$. So we have to find a contradiction to $tr(A^3)=0$ given that each column/row of $A$ sum to $n+1$.

Comment: The formulation in your last sentence is asking for more than the problem asks for, and it is false. It is possible to have triangle-free $3n$-vertex $(n+1)$-regular graphs. However, the college structure tells us that, additionally, the graph is tripartite.

Answer (score 0):

Call the three colleges A, B, and C.

Let Alice be a student at A. If Alice knows $k$ students at B and $n+1-k$ students at C, then we would be done if any of those $k(n+1-k)$ B-C pairs also knew each other. If this *does not* happen, then each Alice's friends at B can have at most $n - (n+1-k)$, or $k-1$ friends at C (excluding all of Alice's friends); similarly, each of Alice's friends at C can have at most $n-k$ friends at B.

When we look at the result of this argument, we should see something odd here. Suppose without loss of generality that $k \le n+1-k$. Then each of Alice's friends at B is "more unbalanced" than Alice: Alice's split of friends is $k$ to $n+1-k$ at the two neighboring colleges, and *their* splits are all $k-1$ to $n+2-k$. In particular, Alice is guaranteed to have a friend who is "more unbalanced" than she is. But Alice was just a random person, and how can it be true that *everyone* has a "more unbalanced" friend? Someone has to be the most unbalanced!

---

To put this observation into action, let's first define what "unbalanced" means. If a student has $x$ friends at one of the neighboring colleges, and $y$ friends at the other (with $x+y$ guaranteed to be $n+1$), let the **unbalance** of that student be the absolute difference $|x-y|$.

Now, find the student (at any of the three colleges) with the greatest unbalance. Without loss of generality, that student goes to college A, so we can name her Alice. Let Alice have $k$ friends at B and $n+1-k$ friends at C, and without loss of generality again, assume that $k < n+1-k$ (making Alice's unbalance $n+1-2k$).

Now, suppose that Bob is one of Alice's friends at college B. Bob's unbalance cannot be greater than Alice's, by assumption! So Bob must have at least $k$ friends at college C. (If Bob had $k-1$ or fewer friends at C, his unbalance would be at least $(n+2-k)-(k-1) = n+3-2k$, greater than Alice's.)

Among the $n$ students at college C, at least $k$ are Bob's friends, and $n+1-k$ are Alice's friends, but this adds up to $n+1$: so there must be overlap. And if Cody at college C is the common friend of Alice and Bob, then together, Alice, Bob, and Cody form a triangle.